# Converting JSON-like object to JSON

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON file that was filtered and lost the original structure. Each line of the file looks like this:

```
{u'spec1': {u'property1': u'12345', u'property2': 1234}, u'spec2': {u'property3': u'98754', u'property4': u'val1'}}
```

`json.loads` doesn't work and `ast.literal_eval` doesn't work. I guess I have 2 issues: remove unicode and change ' to ". Can anyone provide some pointers on where to start?

Comment: `ast.literal_eval` works: http://ideone.com/skIcxY

Comment: What version of python are you using? I had Python 3.2 and it failed but updating to Python 3.4 works. Python 2.7 also works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using Python 2.X.

`json.loads` takes a `str` or `unicode` as its param. The string you give is not a valid json string. So we should do some pre-cooking work.

```
import re, json

json_str = """{u'spec1': {u'property1': u'12345', u'property2': 1234}, u'spec2': {u'property3': u'98754', u'property4': u'val1'}}"""
json_str = json_str.replace("\'", "\"")
json_str = re.sub(r"u\"", "\"", json_str)

json_dict = json.loads(json_str)
```

Then the `json_dict` will be a dictionary inflated from your json string.

Comment: {u'spec1': {u'property1': u'12345', u'property2': 1234},
 u'spec2': {u'property3': u'98754', u'property4': u'val1'}} is what I get as a result

Comment: @user20150316 result of which step?

Comment: print json_dict. json_str looks OK. But json_dict has u'

Comment: @user20150316 So it means you've got the right result of `json.loads`

Comment: All this precooking seems a little tedious. What we are having here is a perfectly working Python objects, so why not try to eval them as such, without all that JSON magic?

Comment: @wswld `eval` may be a little out of control.

Comment: Well we could use `ast.literal_eval` which is a little more stable. Don't get me wrong I think every solution is *right* as far as it does the job and makes OP happy. I just wanted to note, that there are a bit more elegant ways to do that (an I don't mean mine specifically). Anyways, this discussion has probably run its course. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this works (in Python3):

```
$ python3.4
Python 3.4.0 (default, Jun 19 2015, 14:20:21) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import json
>>> j = """{u'spec1': {u'property1': u'12345', u'property2': 1234}, u'spec2': {u'property3': u'98754', u'property4': u'val1'}}"""
>>> json.loads(j.replace("'","\"").replace('u"','"'))
{'spec1': {'property1': '12345', 'property2': 1234}, 'spec2': {'property4': 'val1', 'property3': '98754'}}
```

As you can see, I've replaced both ' to " chars, and (thus came) u" to " patterns.

Hope this helps.

a.

Comment: I am using Python 2.7 and the output still has u'

Comment: Of course, this works in Python 2(.7 and below), I just wrote the Python 3, cause' somebody wrote, he uses Python 3, and something is wrong at there. :)

Comment: @user20150316: yes, in Python 3, the default encoding of all string is unicode, therefore there isn't any prefix to show, the string is unicode (with "u'"). In Python 2, there isn't, therefore it must be show the prefix, if string is unicode.

See: https://wiki.python.org/moin/Python2orPython3
"The most drastic improvement is the better Unicode support (with all text strings being Unicode by default)..."

Answer (score 1):

Here is my take (Python 2.7).

```
import StringIO
import ast
file = u"""{u'spec1': {u'property1': u'12345', u'property2': 1234}, u'spec2': {u'property3': u'98754', u'property4': u'val1'}}
{u'spec2': {u'property1': u'12345', u'property2': 1234}, u'spec3': {u'property3': u'98754', u'property4': u'val1'}}
{u'spec4': {u'property1': u'12345', u'property2': 1234}, u'spec2': {u'property5': u'98754', u'property4': u'val1'}}
{u'spec6': {u'property1': u'12345', u'property2': 1234}, u'spec2': {u'property7': u'98754', u'property4': u'val1'}}
"""
buffer = StringIO.StringIO(file)
lines = buffer.readlines()
dicts = []
for line in lines:
    dicts.append(ast.literal_eval(line))
print dicts
```

Don't look at `StringIO`, it's there to emulate file-reading. What I'm proposing is to read the file by line and do `literal_eval` by line.

For me it was the only way to make it work without errors.